# Why is the constant in Montgomery Curve code 121665 instead of 486662 in the formula?

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation

In the Montgomery Curve $y^2=x^3+486662x^2+x$, $A=486662$. So, why when applying its code in Python or another programming language, $A=121665$?

```
import os
import binascii


P = 2 ** 255 - 19
A24 = 121665
def cswap(swap, x_2, x_3):
    dummy = swap * ((x_2 - x_3) % P)
    x_2 = x_2 - dummy
    x_2 %= P
    x_3 = x_3 + dummy
    x_3 %= P
    return (x_2, x_3)

# Based on https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7748
def X25519(k, u):
    x_1 = u
    x_2 = 1
    z_2 = 0
    x_3 = u
    z_3 = 1
    swap = 0

    for t in reversed(range(255)):
        k_t = (k >> t) & 1
        swap ^= k_t
        x_2, x_3 = cswap(swap, x_2, x_3)
        z_2, z_3 = cswap(swap, z_2, z_3)
        swap = k_t

        A = x_2 + z_2
        A %= P

        AA = A * A
        AA %= P

        B = x_2 - z_2
        B %= P

        BB = B * B
        BB %= P

        E = AA - BB
        E %= P

        C = x_3 + z_3
        C %= P

        D = x_3 - z_3
        D %= P

        DA = D * A
        DA %= P

        CB = C * B
        CB %= P

        x_3 = ((DA + CB) % P)**2
        x_3 %= P

        z_3 = x_1 * (((DA - CB) % P)**2) % P
        z_3 %= P

        x_2 = AA * BB
        x_2 %= P

        z_2 = E * ((AA + (A24 * E) % P) % P)
        z_2 %= P

    x_2, x_3 = cswap(swap, x_2, x_3)
    z_2, z_3 = cswap(swap, z_2, z_3)

    return (x_2 * pow(z_2, P - 2, P)) % P

def decodeScalar25519(k):
  k_list = [(b) for b in k]
  k_list[0] &= 248
  k_list[31] &= 127
  k_list[31] |= 64
  return decodeLittleEndian(k_list)

def decodeLittleEndian(b):
    return sum([b[i] << 8*i for i in range( 32 )])

def unpack2(s):
    if len(s) != 32:
        raise ValueError('Invalid Curve25519 scalar (len=%d)' % len(s))
    t = sum((ord(s[i]) ) << (8 * i) for i in range(31))
    t += (((ord(s[31]) ) & 0x7f) << 248)
    return t    

def pack(n):
    return ''.join([chr((n >> (8 * i)) & 255) for i in range(32)])

def clamp(n):
    n &= ~7
    n &= ~(128 << 8 * 31)
    n |= 64 << 8 * 31
    return n

# Return nP
def multscalar(n, p):
    n = clamp(decodeScalar25519(n))
    p = unpack2(p)
    return pack(X25519(n, p))

# Start at x=9. Find point n times x-point
def base_point_mult(n):
    n = clamp(decodeScalar25519(n))
    return pack(X25519(n, 9))
```

Comment: [**EDITED**] Read [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#section-5) which contains elements of answer then [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/109307/edit) the question to tell what is clear and what's not after (or in) that material. Independently: it appears `cswap` is trying to conditionally swap it's arguments in constant time, but fails. That makes it a strange object of study, especially if it comes without warning of that fact. Python is neither appropriate nor intended for constant-time code.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150714/discussion-on-question-by-nawras-hussein-in-montgomery-curve-y2x3486662x2x).

Answer (score 7):

It is a simple reason; the below is from the [Montgomery paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7.pdf) page 261:

$$Z_{2n} = (4X_nZ_n)((X_n-Z_n)^2+(\color{red}{(A+2)/4)}(4X_nZ_n))$$

Where we have $A = 486662 $

Instead of calculating the $(A+2)/4$ every time, we precalculate to get $$(486662+2)/4 = 121666$$, as Montgomery discusses at the end of the page.

So, the $A$ is not changed, just pre-calculated and named $A24$ as a little indication of adding $2$ then dividing by $4$.

- Why does the RFC use $(486662-2)/4 =  121665$?

  This is from the Appendix B of the [Curve25519 paper](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) where the proof needs to be followed.

Comment: excuse me, but (486662+2)/4 = 121666 not 121665 !

Comment: Ok, that is due to the way they calculated. coming..

Comment: @NawrasHussein Unfortunately, there is no simple explanation for this other than he Appendix B of the original Curve255 paper.